# How to set an RSpec expectation for an object that doesn't exist yet

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

How would I test that a message is sent to `MyCoolClass` when a record is created?

```
describe MyModel, type: :model do
  it 'should call this class' do
    # how do I set the expectation of new_record_id?
    expect_any_instance_of(MyCoolClass).to receive(:a_method).with(new_record_id, :created)
    MyModel.create
  end
end
```

The only alternative is this:

```
describe MyModel, type: :model do
  it 'should call this class' do
    new_record = MyModel.new
    expect_any_instance_of(MyCoolClass).to receive(:a_method).with(new_record, :created)
    new_record.save
  end
end
```

The problem here, though is that I'm testing `save`, not `create`, which is mostly ok for my case. But the bigger problem is that it means I have to change the implementation of `MyCoolClass` to be passed a record, instead of the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two variants

1) use [`anything`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-7/docs/argument-matchers/general-matchers#anything-argument-matcher) or [`kind_of(Numeric)`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#argument-matchers)

```
it 'should call this class' do
  expect_any_instance_of(MyCoolClass).to receive(:a_method).with(kind_of(Numeric), :created)
  MyModel.create
end
```

2) Stub `save` or `create` method and return `double`

```
let(:my_model) { double(id: 123, save: true, ...) }

it 'should call this class' do
  MyModel.stub(:new).and_return(my_model)
  expect_any_instance_of(MyCoolClass).to receive(:a_method).with(my_model.id, :created)
  MyModel.create
end
```

Comment: Very clever. I didn't think of either of these. Thanks!